# What does it mean when the global gradient norm keeps decreasing while loss has converged?

Tags: neural-networks, stochastic-gradient-descent

I am training an autoencoder with a $L^2$ loss. Training gives reasonable results and the loss quickly converge to a non-zero but acceptable value after about 5 epochs:

[image]

However, looking at the "global gradient norm" (the norm of the gradient with respect to all model parameters), I see that it keeps decreasing after the loss seemingly converged.

[image]

I am surprised because I expected that a flatlining loss would imply that the model converged, or at least that the model hops and buzzes between equivalent places of the parameters. But it seems it is still evolving to non-equivalent models, meaning that the optimization is still proceeding even though the loss has flatlined.

How to interpret those findings?

Answer (score 1):

Neural nets have thousand or millions of parameters so you're solving an optimization problem in a very high dimensional space. Thus the likelihood that you will exactly solve the minimization problem at hand is extremely small. When we say that the network's performance "has converged," we don't generally mean, in the context of neural networks, that the exactly optimal weights have been found. Rather, we mean that the network parameters are in some small neighborhood around a locally optimal solution.

So the reason the norm of the gradient is still decreasing is that even though, for all intents and purposes, you should think of the network as having arrived at a local optimum, the parameters are still very slowly tending to that exact point.